# How to do clipping mask

Tags: php

I am trying to place image on alphabets as following

[image]

I need to apply different fonts to text as well.

For this, I have explored PHP GD library and gone through stackoverflow but did not get any idea means how can i accomplish this?

can anyone give me an idea to achieve this goal?

Comment: Css. http://blogs.adobe.com/dreamweaver/2015/07/css-vs-svg-graphical-text.html

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I try it and see if it works for me

Comment: @Andreas It only works in Chrome. Mozilla does not support background-clip css tag

Comment: hmm... Well at least here you can have a fallback http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html . What is the intended use? Is it a header image? In that case photoshop and a jpeg is 100% foolproof

Comment: It is for product personalization.

Comment: This also does not work in Mozilla and Internet Explorer but thanks for continuous suggestions.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is hard because all browsers do not use all functions. This is probably one of those things that you may have to surrender from. The only idea I have left on how to solve this is to load the full image in to php and the delete (make them black) pixels to create the desired result. This is most likely a nightmare to get working, but if you get it right it might be a library you can sell for a few $. My knowledge of how to manipulate a image is very limited, I use it but barely knows what I'm doing. I think the first thing to do is to calculate the width of each

Comment: Letter. And how that relates to a image size (height and width). Once you have a way of drawing a negative of each letter you can just scale it up. I think...